# C++ automatic constrctor call

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, casting

Let's say we have got a raw C-style string `"test"`. We can declare a function like this:

```
void printText(std::string textToPrint){
   std::cout << textToPrint << "\n";
}
```

and we may call it in a following manner:

```
printText("test");
```

And this should be perfectly fine, as argument is an object, not a reference, so temporary object like `std::string("test")` should be created in time of calling function `printText()'.

Now given that, I have a following template:

```
template <typename T>
T checkMe(Proxy<T> arg){
    std::cout << arg() << std::endl;
    return arg();
}
```

where `Proxy` class declaration is as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class Proxy{
public:
    Proxy(std::function<T&()> caller);
    Proxy(std::shared_ptr<T> dataPtr);
    T& operator()();
private:
    std::function<T&()> m_functional;
    std::shared_ptr<T> m_data;
};
```

It's purpose is to make some of the functions be called with two object types:
One is `shared_ptr` to the data and another is functional object, that returns this type of data.

Now when I want to call function `checkMe` error happens, that I do not know why appears and how to solve it. One thing is:

```
getMe(std::make_shared<int>(255));
```

And this in my opinion should be perfectly fine, as Proxy's constructor takes shared_ptr as argument and creates itself based on it. But this gives compiler's deduction error. Whereas, when I call function like this:

```
getMe<int>(std::make_shared<int>(255));
```

Well now it's fine. I do not know why does compiler cannot deduce the type on it's own.

Second case is calling it with a functional object:

```
getMe<int>(std::bind(getNumberMult,5,6));
```

Where `getNumberMult` is defined as follows:

```
int xy;
int& getNumberMult(int x, int y){
    return xy = x*y;
}
```

Here conversion error occurs. Could someone please specify is it possible and how to achieve desired behavior of the given code and explain what is wrong with my understanding of the mechanism? I would like to use this code as follows:

```
getMe(std::make_shared<int>(300));
getMe(std::bind(getNumberMult, 6, 7));
```

Compiler errors:

when using

```
getMe<int>(std::bind(getNumberMult, 5, 6));

path/to/file:36: error: C2664: 'T getMe<int>(DataProxy<T>)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::_Bind<true,int &,int &(__cdecl *const )(int,int),int,int>' to 'DataProxy<int>'
with
[
    T=int
]
```

Comment: A copy of the actual compiler message is mandatory.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+non-deducible+context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `T checkMe(Proxy<T> arg)`, `arg` should be a `Proxy<T>` (or inherit from it).

Compiler doesn't check the infinite possibilities to test each `Proxy<T>` can be construct from given argument.

Answer (score 0):

So generally I know now why it is so, and what should I do to fix it.

Consider following object:

```
struct Test{
    Test(std::string someString){}
};
```

So we need std::string just for constructing object of this class.

We can do without `std::string` created explicitly in following manner:

```
int main(){
    Test someVariable("someRawString");
}
```

It's gonna work and it is completely fine. What happens underhood is:

- compiler meets instruction for creating object of `Test` class
- It sees, that given argument is not of type required by Constructor
- because of the fact, that required argument is a value, not a reference (const reference would also be fine) it creates temporary object of type `std::string` and passes this temporary object to the constructor
- Object is successfully created.

Now let's consider function:

```
void someTestFunction(Test someTest){}
```

It requires object of type `Test`, that is constructed from `std::string`

Given that, it should be fine to invoke this function in following manner:

```
someTestFunction("someRawText");
```

But it's not fine. This gives us error of converting arguments. Reason for it is quite simple: C++ allows only one step of converting, when passing parameters to the function. So compiler can:

- cast raw string to `std::string`
- create `Test` object with `std::string`

But it cannot:

- cast raw string to `std::string`
- cast `std::string` to `Test` (too many conversions)
- invoke function with Test

Exactly the same things happened with the given code. To make it work we should use:

```
getMe<int>(std::make_shared<int>(300));
getMe<int>(std::function<int&()>(std::bind(getNumberMult, 6, 7)));
```

Why is it so?

`std::make_shared<int>` has return type of `std::shared_ptr<int>`, so no conversion was required to invoke a function.

`std::bind...` has a returning type different than `std::function`, it has it's own implementation defined return type. That is why this second cast would be required here, which is not allowed by C++. When we cast it explicitly, then only one implicit cast is required and everything works fine.